# CSS - Wrapping very last text to another line if it doesn't fit

Tags: css, line-breaks, word-wrap

I have a link at the very end of 4 paragraphs.  Something like:

```
Here is my text, and it's just an example of text to show
And I am wanting to wrap the last bit of text, which happens
to be a link, but I need the link to either stay on the line
that is the available width and not break to another line,
unless it can't fit left-aligned on that line like this
http://mylink.com
```

So, the actual code for this would be as follows in HTML:

```
<p>Here is my text, and it's just an example of text to show
And I am wanting to wrap the last bit of text, which happens
to be a link, but I need the link to either stay on the line
that is the available width and not break to another line,
unless it can't fit left-aligned on that line like this<br />
<a href="http://mylink.com">http://mylink.com</a></p>
```

I am using `<br />` here, but I don't want to use `<br />` because the screen captures how much text actually shows and sometimes it could look like this:

```
Here is my text, and it's just an example of text to show And I am wanting to wrap
the last bit of text, which happens to be a link, but I need the link to either stay
on the line that is the available width and not break to another line, unless it can't 
fit left-aligned on that line like this
http://mylink.com
```

So, in a situation like above, I would need it to not use a `<br />` tag to break it up and it should render like this instead:

```
Here is my text, and it's just an example of text to show And I am wanting to wrap
the last bit of text, which happens to be a link, but I need the link to either stay
on the line that is the available width and not break to another line, unless it can't 
fit left-aligned on that line like this http://mylink.com
```

Is this possible to do via CSS?  Some `text-align` value perhaps, or something else in order to accomplish this without using `<br />` tags at all?  But if the link can fit on the line naturally, than it shouldn't move to the next line down.  Instead it should stay on that line.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some browsers interpret the slash in your URL as a character it is allowed to break your *word* on, while others will not.  All you should need to do is adjust the white-space property of the link

http://jsfiddle.net/Msc4S/

```
a {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this html as you want:

```
<p>Here is my text, and it's just an example of text to show
And I am wanting to wrap the last bit of text, which happens
to be a link, but I need the link to either stay on the line
that is the available width and not break to another line,
unless it can't fit left-aligned on that line like this
<a href="http://mylink.com">http://mylink.com</a></p>
```

But add this into the CSS.

```
a {
    display: block;
}
```

However this will make `a` on the new line everywhere, so you have to specify it more with this CSS

```
p a {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/vzmtB/ (without using `p a`) and http://jsfiddle.net/vzmtB/1/ (with using `p a`).

Comment: I think you misunderstand what I am trying to do.  Take a few words off of the end of your jsfiddle example, and you'll notice that the link stays on the next line down.  Which is not what I'm asking for.  I need it to fill that line, if the entire link can fit on that line, otherwise, it will need to go on a new line.

Comment: Well then add more examples into your question.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the entire question.  I actually provide an example of just this.

Comment: No you can't do it with CSS, it would be difficult to do with JS as well.

Comment: @DanielImms - Ohh, that really stinks! :( :(  I wonder if this can be done with jQuery by calculating width of the last line of text and the width of the link...?

Comment: @SolomonClosson I'm not aware how you would go about getting the last line of a <p> in jQuery.

Comment: Well, I could change it to use `span` tags after every group of words also...  I can change the HTML anyway I want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the default word-wrap without break does this already. when some thing doesn't fit in line It moves to next line, but If it can be fit then it doesn't move to next line. You need to have a defined width of parent element, in which text gonna be fit. [check this fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/qfVUq/1/)

```
nothing you need to do in css.
```

Comment: Nope, if it were that simple, I wouldn't ask this question.  In your jsfiddle, the link wraps around to the next line.  What I need is, if the ENTIRE link will not fit on the line naturally, than move it to a new line, otherwise, keep it on that line.  It sounds extremely simple, as if somehow, this should've been part of CSS somewhere, and something went wrong that never got this implemented in it!

Comment: hmmm I didn't get you. What you mean by entire link ? If a word is linked, then the word will not break. It will come in same line, If it can be ift, but if it don't then it will come in next line. In second paragraph link doesn't fit in line, so it came in next line. [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfVUq/2/)

Comment: But I'm not really using `http://mylink.com` for the link, I'm using words for the link like:  `<a href="http://mylink.com">This is my link</a>` but in any case, your example still shows the link wrapping (mid-way in between the link) to the next line.  So part of it is on the 2nd to last line, and the rest of the link is on the last line (even with it being 1 word... the actual link).

Comment: If you having more than a word in link text then I think you need set white-space; to anchor tag [check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfVUq/4/) . **edited**:- ohh man, i didn't see above answer. It already answered.